# The specified type member 'UserName' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to show images from a specific user by using the id parameter in the url but I get this error message:

> The specified type member 'UserName' is not supported in LINQ to
>   Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported.

This is my action method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Show(String id)
{
    var images = new List<Image>();
    var db = new portfolio_project_db();

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
        images = db.Images.Where(x => x.UserName == id).ToList();

        return View(images);
    }
}
```

I have read more about this error and from what I understand people get this because the variable is not a column in the database, but I do have an UserName field in my table Image.

```
public partial class Image
{
    public int ImageID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

}

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Image] (
    [ImageID]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Title]     VARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [ImagePath] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [UserID]    INT            NULL,
    [UserName] NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ImageID] ASC)
);
```

What do I need to do differently?

---

Requested:

```
    public partial class portfolio_project_db : DbContext
    {
    public portfolio_project_db()
        : base("name=portfolio_project_db")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us your table schema in the table?

Comment: The error is very obvious: `UserName` is not part of the table definition schema.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I am sorry, but could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: .SelectMany.Where(---) will work maybe?

Comment: could you show us the `portfolio_project_db` class ?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto: Please check this out, if you haven't already: https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change  Thanks!

Comment: @Sandra, your linq query looks correct to me... I feel you may not have included the cause of this error in your question... Why is `Images` marked as Virtual? Are you overriding it somewhere else?

Comment: @Hooman Virtual? Do you mean Partial?

Comment: public virtual DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }

Comment: yaa..very funny, as i could not reproduce the problem on my side. Btw still curious, how do you create the table? was it from migration ? and also can you confirm UserName exist in the table? (through server explorer perhaps)

Comment: The existence of `UnintentionalCodeFirstException()` means that you're using either Database First or Model First, can you ensure that the property is already mapped in EDMX file? Also usually `DbSet` is declared as `public DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }`, without `virtual` keyword.

Comment: @Hooman I have no idea honestly, any way for me to figure it out?

Comment: @RizkiDPrast Ok, good to know. No, no migration. I just created it using the designer. And yes, the column exists in the server explorer.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto  i think `virtual` is the correct one on DbSet as it will make mocking in UnitTest works

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Now I noticed that UserName does not exist in the edmx file. I thought adding it to Image.cs was enough. My bad! So do I need to create a new data model everytime I am changing the design of my tables?

Comment: In the package manager console, enable migrations and execute `update-database` to reflect entity changes to the database schema.

Comment: @Sandra your approach is Database first. you have .edmx file already, so every time you update the database, all you have to do is open .edmx > right click then `UpdateModelFrom database`. you should not generate model manually

Comment: @Sandra Every time you added new column in database, you need to regenerate the data model class by `Update Model from Database` option in EDMX designer. It automatically generates property name and its mapping type. If you not using that option, you need to edit the EDMX file in text/XML editor and create your own property mapping (which is not recommended).

Comment: Works now, thanks guys.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Post it as an answer, so Sandra can accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The specified type member 'UserName' is not supported in LINQ to Entities* message indicates that the property `UserName` is still not mapped to `UserName` column in database. Here are the steps to enable property mapping in Database First configuration (because `UnintentionalCodeFirstException()` exists in `OnModelCreating()` method):

**a. Using EDMX designer (recommended)**

1) Remove existing `UserName` property from `Image` data model class.

2) Open the EDMX file of your model in entity designer, then right click in any empty space of designer surface and choose `Update Model from Database` option.

3) Save all changes in EDMX designer, now the `UserName` property is automatically 
 created and mapped with `UserName` column in database.

**b. Edit EDMX file to create mapping (advanced - not recommended)**

This approach requires editing the EDMX file to add mapping property manually by adding property name in both `<edmx:StorageModels>`, `<edmx:ConceptualModels>` and `<edmx:Mappings>` section:

```html
<!-- for edmx:StorageModels -->
<Property Name="UserName" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="20" Nullable="false" />

<!-- for edmx:ConceptualModels -->
<Property Name="UserName" Type="String" MaxLength="20" FixedLength="false" Unicode="true" Nullable="false" />

<!-- for edmx:Mappings -->
<ScalarProperty Name="UserName" ColumnName="UserName" />
```

**Note:** Every time you added or updated column(s) and/or table schema in database, you should update the model to reflect all changes from database into data model classes.